# Visualization library suggestions

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts, visualization, data-visualization

I'm hoping to build a visualization like in the picture. Could anyone offer some suggestions on the best Javascript or CSS visualization library to use? I'd prefer to use HighCharts since I'm familiar with it, but I'm not sure if the stacked bar chart is the best option here, though I think it would be relatively straightforward to implement. Any thoughts? If you could refer me to the appropriate docs/tutorials, that'd be great!

[image: Percentages]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need some advanced functionality (interactivity) for this visualization, maybe some library could be an overkill.

If this case was my task, I would **roll my own simple visualization in JavaScript or jQuery**.

For more advanced visualization, I would use the [D3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3) library.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. I don't think this would be too bad to just roll it. Thanks for the suggestion!